# Meaning of extra $ variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I want to know about meaning of $$val; what is the actual meaning is?i tried to find meaning of this in google but not understand properly. Please help me in this situations.

For example: suppose i have one variable which has `$$value;`
meaning of $$value?

Comment: What *language* are you talking about? Please edit your question and add a suitable tag.

Comment: Tags belong in the tags, not in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put the language, but I'll assume you mean PHP

That's a variable variable.

That means you ware asking for the value of the variable whose name.is the first variable.

Here's an example, since that's quite confusing:

```
$foo = "Hi";
$bar = "world";
$world = "Hello!";

echo $$bar; // "Hello!"
```

php fiddle:  http://ideone.com/Ve4YOO

Reference: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php